# Reviewing an edit isn't possible from tools page

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

I was looking at the [flags queue](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=flags) and noticed a badly misformatted question. Naturally, it was saying "edit (1)" below it - somebody already proposed an edit and one person approved it. So I clicked it but instead of letting me review the edit the page scrolled to the top - the JavaScript code didn't run or failed, the usual `href="#"` took over instead. Going to the question and approving the edit there worked then.

Unfortunately, I don't see any more pending edits for flagged posts to make a screenshot. No free-hand circles this time...

Comment: I've seen this before, but to be honest opening the question didn't seem like a huge deal. The annoying thing is that the button is there but doesn't work.

Comment: No, definitely not a big deal. Still, it's a bug and it doesn't seem to be documented yet.

Comment: It happens also on admin/dashboard, which is the moderator's equivalent of tools/flagged for moderators.